# How to remove duplicate value (except null)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My DB has some documents like:

```
id               user_id
1                1
2                2
3                2
4                null
5                null
```

I want get all document, but only get the first one if duplicate `user_id`, but `not null`

Expect result:

```
id               user_id
1                1
2                2
4                null
5                null
```

I have try `$group`, but it will remove duplicate null user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$facet` to separate both null result and without null result,
- `$project` to combine both arrays using $concatArrays
- `$unwind` deconstruct array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace root object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      nullResult: [{ $match: { user_id: null } }],
      result: [
        { $match: { user_id: { $ne: null } } },
        { $group: { _id: "$user_id" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      root: { $concatArrays: ["$nullResult", "$result"] }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-kWA1hsnEck)